# How can I open a newWindow with whatever is in src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iFrame where I am pushing some html files. But when the iFrame is loaded I show a button which on click I want to open that html from src in a new window.

So my code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="player-container">
    <div class='page-title'></div>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="" class="page-iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#iframe').one('load', function(){
        $('.btn').show();  
    })
    $('.btn').on('click', function(){
        window.open('whatever is in iframe src');
    })
```

Does anyone has any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` is an attribute, you can read it with `attr`:

```
$('#iframe').one('load', function(){
    $('.btn').show();  
});
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    window.open($("#iframe").attr("src"));
})
```

Comment: Speed matters while answering.. :D +1 :)

Comment: @MarkusHayner: Good deal.